# Where do I put the logic to run a function when a user firsts registers an account?

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, passport-google-oauth

Im using Node.js and I want to run a function ONLY when a user REGISTERS a new account. This function is going to add some unique info their user object when they sign up.

I am using passport with googleoauth2.0. I will also be using passport local, and passport facebook on this webapp.

Should I put the logic in the passport.js file? (the file that creates the user in the first place)

Im a new programmer and just curious how this should be done.

Here is my passport.js file below

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const FacebookStrategy = require('passport-facebook').Strategy;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const keys = require('../config/keys');

const User = mongoose.model('users');

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
    done( null, user.id) // turning user model instance into an id 
});

passport.deserializeUser((id, done) => {
        User.findById(id).then(user => {
            done(null,user)
        })
})

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        clientID: keys.googleClientID,
        clientSecret: keys.googleClientSecret,
        callbackURL: '/auth/google/callback',
        proxy: true
    },
    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
        console.log(profile)
        const existingUser = await User.findOne({googleId: profile.id})
        if (existingUser) {
            done(null, existingUser)
                } else {// possibly send the post request here to create a new service instance?
                    const user = await new User({ 
                        googleId: profile.id,
                        displayName: profile.displayName,
                        image: profile.photos[0].value,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        firstName: profile.name.givenName,
                        lastName: profile.name.familyName }).save()
                   // can I put a function in between here to add unique info to this newly created user object? or is this a bad practice?

How do I run a function after the .save() but before the done?
                    done(null, user);
                }
        }
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do a common search by a unique field and if the result is undefined it'll mean it is the first signup

```
const user = new User({ 
  googleId: profile.id,
  displayName: profile.displayName,
  image: profile.photos[0].value,
  email: profile.emails[0].value,
  firstName: profile.name.givenName,
  lastName: profile.name.familyName });

let attemptToFindUser = await User.findOne({email: user.email});

if(!attemptToFindUser){
 //This is the fist signup from this user, do your stuff here. 
}

//Then;

await user.save()
```